# Android instrument test wipes the shared preference data while loading native library

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

When I create Android Instrumentation test case below, I find a strange issue. With the line of loading native lib `System.loadLibrary("jnidispatch");`, the test case is failed; without that line the test case is working fine. I test with any native libraries, the issue is same, so it is not because of the native library behavior to wipe out the shared preference. It seems a bug of android instrumentation test, any one can explain why?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    private static final String MY_ID = "MY_ID";
    private static final String TEST_DATA = "Test";

    @Test
    public void sharedPreferenceTest() {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
        // Set ID
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(MY_ID, TEST_DATA);
        editor.apply();

        System.loadLibrary("jnidispatch"); // load native libary

        // Get ID
        SharedPreferences sharedPref1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String data = sharedPref1.getString(MY_ID, null);
        Assert.assertEquals(data, TEST_DATA);
    }
}
```

[The sample project can be downloaded here.](https://github.com/hwdavr/AndroidInstrumentTest)

**UPDATE:** In the end I found out it's the device issue, the issue only happens on certain device, like OPPO device.